# Visual Studio Code TypeScript: why cant see map in bluebird package

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, bluebird

I'm install bluebird package in my project and does not working in my pc...

I don't have any idea.
This is my code:

```
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
import * as express from "express";
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";
import * as bluebird from "bluebird";
import * as session from "express-session";

// Load environment variables from .env file, where API keys and passwords are configured
dotenv.config({ path: ".env.myenv" });

// Controllers (route handlers)
import * as homeController from "./controllers/home";

// Create Express server
const app = express();

// Connect to MongoDB
const mongoUrl:any = process.env.MONGOLAB_URI;
(<any>mongoose).Promise = bluebird;
mongoose.connect(mongoUrl, {useMongoClient: true}).then(
  () => { /** ready to use. The `mongoose.connect()` promise resolves to undefined. */ },
).catch(err => {
  console.log("MongoDB connection error. Please make sure MongoDB is running. " + err);
  // process.exit();
});


app.get("/", homeController.index);


app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Hello World');
});

module.exports = app;
```

When i try build for js file : tsc src/app.ts compiller catch this error

[image]

node_modules/@types/bluebird/index.d.ts  This one error :

[image]

and This one :
[image]

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using? It's possible that you have an old version which does not natively define the `Map` type.

Comment: Typescript Version :  2.6.2

Comment: I see. Pretty sure that version should support `Map<K, V>`.